# Not able to run react native app in Android Emulator - using EXPO cli

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Installed the expo cli using 
"npm install -g expo-cli" and create a project 
expo init AwesomeProject.
I have the android emulator running ,see the installed version in the image

but when i try to run the expo project using "npm run android" getting error as 
**Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: unable to get local issuer certificate**
can any one help me on this thanks..
[SDK tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iEIN.png)  [image: SDk platform]  [image: error image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Experiencing the same problem.

Comment: issue was with network, changed to open network instead of closed network , it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the guide on:
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

Can you run adb from your terminal?

```
$adb version
```